# When dealing with an improper antiderivative, why do you take the limit from the left?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

The example I have is $$\left[\tan x+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}$$

In my mind, you treat it as a limit as $x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$

However, apparently it its $$\lim _{x\to \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^-}\left(\tan x+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)$$ because "you approach $\frac{π}{2}$ from the left".

Why is that so? The source is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJzAp_NSsbM&t=0s (timestamp 4:45)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you want to compute$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}\,\mathrm dt.\tag1$$Note that this is an improper integral, since $\frac{1+\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}$ is undefined at $\frac\pi2$. So, $(1)$ actually means$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}\int_0^x\frac{1+\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}\,\mathrm dt\tag2$$and therefore, since $\tan+\frac1\cos$ is a primitive of $\frac{1+\sin}{\cos^2}$, $(2)$ is equal to$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}\left[\tan(t)+\frac1{\cos(t)}\right]_{t=0}^{t=x}.$$

Comment: What? My question is *why* you take the limit as $x\rightarrow {\frac{π}{2}}^{-1}$ in the first place.

Comment: Indeed. And I provided an answer to that question.

Comment: If its undefined at $π/2$, why do you take the limit towards negative $π/2$ and not just $π/2$?

Comment: Because if $f$ is a function fro $[a,b)$ into $\Bbb R$, then, by definition,$$\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\lim_{x\to b^-}\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$Sometimes peoble just write $\lim_{x\to b}$, but it's the same thing in this context, since $f$ is only defined to the left of $b$.

Comment: Ahh ok. I did not know that. Thank you - is there a name for the definition?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

Because the integral
$$\int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{1-\sin{x}}dx$$
is not defined on the interval $[0,a]$ with $a > \pi/2$, so you are considering it on the interval $[0,a]$, $a < \pi/2$, and letting $a \to \pi/2^{-}$.

Comment: But why do you approach $π/2$ from the negative side? I graphed it on desmos and see that it is indeed an improper integral so it is not defined for the above first value for $a$.

Comment: @user71207 What do you mean the "negative side"? (and what is the "above first value for $a$?) This notation means you approach the limit "from the left" (thinking of the number line going left to right), meaning values of $a < \pi/2$; think of values of $a$ **close to** $\pi/2$, but smaller; and from there, approaching $\pi/2$.

Comment: @user71207 The point is, the interval **is defined** for any $0 < a < \pi/2$, and **is not defined** for any $a > \pi/2$. The number $-\pi/2$ does not come into it at all (related to your comment on another answer)

Comment: Ok yes you have found where my mistake was. It was an erroneous understanding but it's all sorted out now. Thanks

Comment: @user71207 No problem, I am glad if this helped understand.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you decide to compute the integral as the Reimann sum

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n g(k) \times \frac{\pi/2}{n},$$

where $g(k)$ is the value of the function $f(x)$ at $x= (k−1) \frac{π/2}{n}$.

Then in this Reimann sum, the value of $f(x)$ at any value $x \geq (\pi/2)$ is totally irrelevant.

Consequently, when examining the limit as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ of the anti-derivative $F(x)$, you dismiss the limit as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ from **above** as totally irrelevant.